# Can't re-run windows 10 from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I'm fairly new to Linux and have never used it before. I had been using windows 10 for a bit and decided that I wanted to try Ubuntu so I installed it beside Windows and I can launch Ubuntu but can't go back to Windows. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you chose to format the whole drive while installing?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode. If Windows was pre-installed then it is UEFI boot mode. But Ubuntu installer has from UEFI boot menu two install modes  UEFI & another which is then the CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode. The two modes are not compatible. You need Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

When your system boots go to BIOS settings [you can go to BIOS settings by hitting F1 or whichever key is assigned to take you to BIOS settings] and from there change boot option.

change the Windows boot option from second or whatever place it may be to first.

Restart your device and the system should boot to windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're fairly new, I think you didn't change the boot option from uefi to legacy.

If you did, that's the error, you should switch back to uefi and than you will be able to see it again.

In this case, just because I think you can install again ubuntu from start, just create a bootable uefi ubuntu usb pen (since this was the error, you will be now on windows, and using something like etcher it will be very easy) and shift+reboot from windows 10 chosing usb pen as a alternative boot device.

You will install now ubuntu as UEFI and the next boot will prompt you to GRUB multiboot options.

If you didn't change anything and you followed some nice guide telling you how to install ubuntu in uefi, well, grub just didn't updated and you have to do it manually:

You have surely seen what is the label of you hd (dev/sdX), just use following commands (if you don't know... I could tell you "what are you doing? You know nothing? It's dangerous! But... use this `sudo lsblk` and you will find that "dev/sdX" normally "a")

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
sudo update-grub
```

Done. You should now be able to see both operating systems.

If this doesn't works....... are you **really really** sure you have installed ***aside*** windows?

On ubuntu on "files" you should see windows partition... if you don't see it... you can start everything from the beginning... just from windows 10.

Comment: @JackAttack, if the answer helped you, please make sure you accept it by using the checkmark.